# Response.redirect in foreach

Tags: loops, foreach, tabs, response, response.redirect

I have a response.redirect inside a foreach loop, it meens that I neet to open several new tabs, but what happens is that it opens one tab and then go out from the loop!
how can I change this?

Comment: In what language or technology?

Comment: Response.Redirect ends current request and tells the browser to navigate to the specified target its not designed for what you are trying to do...if you could elaborate more on what you want to achieve, maybe I can give you another solution.